# what is the difference between the \L and the lc function in Perl?

Tags: string, perl

What is the difference between \L and lc in Perl?

Where are these two applicable?

Comment: why you remove my thanks?

Comment: ruggedbuteducated, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lc` is a function that takes an expression and returns the lowercase version of that expression.  `\L` is used as a way to make letters in a substring lower case (is terminated by `\E`)

For example:

```
print lc("STeve");
#prints steve  

print "DOW\LNLO\EAD\n";
#prints DOWnloAD
```

Comment: shall i use lc or \L when using cmp on hash values? example: $thishash{$a} cmp $thishash{$b}; and i want them to be lowercased

Comment: Feeding them to `lc` seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

```
"foo\Lbar\Ebaz"
```

is just another way of writing

```
"foo".lc("bar")."baz"
```

It happens after interpolation, so

```
"foo\L$bar\Ebaz"
```

is just another way of writing

```
"foo".lc($bar)."baz"
```

`\L..\E` is useful in the substitution operator's replacement expression which is a string literal.

```
s/(...)(...)(...)/\L$1\E!$2!\L$3\E/
```

To use `lc`, you'd have to use `/e`

```
s/(...)(...)(...)/ lc($1)."!$2!".lc($3) /e
```